# How to custom rectangle progress bar?

Tags: ios, objective-c, progress-bar, uiprogressview, uiprogressbar

I want to custom a rectangle progress bar with UIKIT like attracted image. Is there any source code for that?
Cocos2d has the same one with CCProgressTimer but I can't find any UIKIT source code.
[image: Rectangle progress bar]

Comment: Hey Toandk, shouldn't you make this answered?  You said it worked; marking it answered will save other people looking at the question and give Dipen the credit he deserves

Answer (score 9):

create a ShapedLayer

```
CAShapeLayer *layer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
[layer setStrokeColor:[UIColor greenColor].CGColor];
[layer setLineWidth:10.0f];

[layer setFillColor:[UIColor clearColor].CGColor];
```

create a rect with radious where you want to animate

```
UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:CGRectMake(10, 10, 300, 200) cornerRadius:10.0f];
layer.path = path.CGPath;

CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"strokeEnd"];
animation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f];
animation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0f];
```

define animation duration

```
animation.duration = 4.0f;
[layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"myStroke"];
```

add animation to layer on which you want to display

```
[self.view.layer addSublayer:layer];
```

Comment: Thank for your codes. It worked. But how can I set the starting point of path in the top middle? I'm not good with CAAnimation

Comment: @SukhmeetHora same here. did you find solution for that ?

Comment: i also need the same and how to change the starting point and the ending point..!

Comment: It's possible to start at every corner using CATransform3DMakeRotation to rotate the layer.

Answer (score 1):

**SWIFT 5 VERSION**

```
    func animation() {
    CATransaction.begin()
    
    let layer : CAShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    layer.strokeColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    layer.lineWidth = 3.0
    layer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    
    let path : UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 84, height: 30), byRoundingCorners: .allCorners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 5.0, height: 0.0))
    layer.path = path.cgPath
    
    let animation : CABasicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
    animation.fromValue = 0.0
    animation.toValue = 1.0
    
    animation.duration = 4.0
    
    CATransaction.setCompletionBlock{ [weak self] in
        if self!.isAdvClick == false {
            self!.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: false)
        }
    }
    
    layer.add(animation, forKey: "myStroke")
    CATransaction.commit()
    self.btnSkip.layer.addSublayer(layer)
}
```

**Here is a code in swift 2.0 for UIButton Border animation**

```
func animation(){
        CATransaction.begin()
        
        let layer : CAShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        layer.strokeColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
        layer.lineWidth = 3.0
        layer.fillColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
        
        let path : UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 84, height: 30), byRoundingCorners: .AllCorners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 5.0, height: 0.0))
        layer.path = path.CGPath
        
        let animation : CABasicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
        animation.fromValue = 0.0
        animation.toValue = 1.0
        
        animation.duration = 4.0
        
        CATransaction.setCompletionBlock{ [weak self] in
            if self!.isAdvClick == false {
                self!.navController?.popViewControllerAnimated(false)
            }
        }
        
        layer.addAnimation(animation, forKey: "myStroke")
        CATransaction.commit()
        self.btnSkip.layer.addSublayer(layer)
    }
```

**You can check out put on this** [Link](https://appetize.io/app/65f124nng9uwpdccrq4pzmamdw)